# Dropping Placemark on current location and separate location mkmapview

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkplacemark

I'm having a few issues with MKMapView! I'm new to the mapping!
What i'm trying to do:

Mapview loads up and drops a placemarker on user's current location, and on the address of the selected customer.
This code drops a placemarker on the address of the selected customer fine, but i can't seem to get it to drop one on the user's current location!

Any ideas why?

```
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:postcodeForMap
             completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                     NSLog(@"Co-ordinate geocode is %@", [placemarks objectAtIndex:0]);
                 for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)

                 {
                     CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                     MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
                     MKPlacemark *mPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate addressDictionary:nil];



                     MKCoordinateRegion region = mapView.region;
                     region.center = placemark.region.center;
                     region.span.longitudeDelta /= 8.0;
                     region.span.latitudeDelta /= 8.0;

                     [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
                     [mapView addAnnotation:placemark];
                     [mapView addAnnotation:mPlacemark];

                 }
             }
 ];
```

Comment: You can use `CLLocationManager` to get user's location..

Comment: Think i have the code for that but i'm not sure how to use it >.< I'll post it in the next comment, could you advise me how to actually use it to drop the placemarker?

Comment: //    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
//    MKMapView *map = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
//    
//    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
//    
//    CLLocationCoordinate2D _coordinate = locationManager.location.coordinate;
//    MKCoordinateRegion extentsRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(_coordinate, 800, 800);
//    
//    [map setRegion:extentsRegion animated:YES];

Comment: Are you able to see the other `placemark` except the `userlocation` ?

Comment: Yes, the placemark for 'postcodeForMap' comes up fine :) It's just the one for userlocation that i can't seem to get to work!

Answer (score 1):

You can get user location using the following code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate=self;//THIS IS IMPORTANT
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

When you tell the location manager to get the locations if `Allowed` the `locationmanager` calls its delegate method see below

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
          //newLocation is your current Location

   self.userLocation=newLocation;//Once you got the location generate the places..
   [self generatePlaces];
   [manager stopUpdatingLocation];

}

-(void)generatePlaces{
  CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:postcodeForMap
             completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                     NSLog(@"Co-ordinate geocode is %@", [placemarks objectAtIndex:0]);
                 for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)

                 {
                     CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                     MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
                     //EDITED
                     MKPlacemark *mPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:self.userLocation.coordinate addressDictionary:nil];



                     MKCoordinateRegion region = mapView.region;
                     region.center = placemark.region.center;
                     region.span.longitudeDelta /= 8.0;
                     region.span.latitudeDelta /= 8.0;

                     [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
                     [mapView addAnnotation:placemark];
                     [mapView addAnnotation:mPlacemark];

                 }
             }
 ];
}
```

Comment: 2 errors for this atm!  1) Can't assign 'newLocation' to userLocation. and 2) it wont let me do the delegate as it says it's Assigning to ID CLLocationManagerDelegate from incompatible type...

Comment: Sorted the delegate issue, had to put it in the header file (obviously!!) just had a silly moment haha!

Answer (score 1):

For Your consideration. It is easy to drop any image or url or pin to user current location.

For that you have to implement.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{

if (annotation == mapView.userLocation)
{

    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;

    return annView;

}
}
```

Comment: I tried having that in there, but i did not know how to actually make it run! I'm not sure what you would put in the viewForAnnotation section of the [self mapView] thing to run it...